# Android ADT r12 for MAC

Tags: android, adt

I am getting an error message regarding a styles.xml on my Eclipse for MAC OS X. Below is the error message:

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:WindowTitleBackground'.`

I googled this issue and found out that I will require an SDK r11 update to solve this problem. But since the latest SDK is r12, I downloaded using my Eclipse. But I still see this problem.

I am new to Android, so I do not really know how to troubleshoot this problem. I am hoping you guys can help me. Do let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bug report where everything is explained: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18659

WindowTitleBackground is a private resource and thus you cannot inherit from it, instead you should copy the parent resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `@android:style/WindowTitleBackground`

You need to specify which type this `@android` is, so adding style should work.

Comment: give me a moment, this is a passed down project...
EDIT: this is done in an xml got style.xml, no where else has the code... 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style name="WindowTitleBackground" parent="@android:style/WindowTitleBackground">
  <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
</resources>

Comment: hm... looks good as I would to it the same way. sorry, no idea :/