# Android R.java file is not creating for my applications

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am creating new Android application in my Eclipse.Application is created but the R.java file is not creating,I am getting errors R cannot be resolved.

IS there any issue in my android-sdk?

Thanks

Comment: did you clean build your project ?

Comment: I am just creating a new application,but my R file is not generrating

Comment: Clean & Build your project or select BuildAutomatically option and create new project.

Comment: no,its not working.My new project itself not generating R file and I am getting errors

Comment: @user1891910-Check my answer...it will surely help u..!!

Answer (score 1):

Try Clean and Build
if it does not work please close the eclipse and open it again
It should work.

Comment: Its ok,I have one more query can I ask now

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things.

1)in `project` tab(topbar) there is **clean** option try that, *if your code is fine it will regenerate R.java file*

2)if you imported `import android.R.*` statements, remove it, You should add your.project.name.R.* instead;

3) there may be *errors in your xml files*, check `error viewer` it should show `errors` there.

Comment: creating new project also not generating R file

Answer (score 0):

Check this. have you imported `import android.R;`in your project. If have means **remove** this `import android.R;`. clean and Rebuild your project

```
import android.R;
```

Comment: You should make sure the imported R should come from package defined in the AndroidManifest file

Answer (score 0):

[No generated R.java file in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project).
[R.Java not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318290/r-java-not-generated).
[R.java file not getting generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869307/r-java-file-not-getting-generated).

When you clean and build your project R.java gets generates automatically. Try the above links.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to  solve this problem:

> 1) In Project Explorer, Right Click on your Project, then go to Build
>   Project
>
> 2)in project tab Go to clean option, if your code is fine it will regenerate R.java file

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and try again it will help u

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipse Menu Bar;

Enable `Project -> Built -> Built Automatically`