# R.Java Not Generating for few Projects

Tags: android

When I am making projects, I face a problem of R.java file not getting generated for few projects.

For rest of my projects it works fine. If there is problem whys is it coming to few projects.

I have updated SDK Tools as well, Cleaned the project, checked for errors but after doing that I came up with no result.

Please help me to resolve the problem if anyone also face the same problem.

Comment: This is a common problem. Use Intellij IDE, it renders project structures much better and has less visible bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I already referred those comment but all worthless.

Anyhow, I have reinstalled everything from begining and now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually already a question out there about this. This is specific to Eclipse, but try to follow the steps listed in this post.

Reference: [R.Java not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318290/r-java-not-generated)